# PHP Mysql select to array format

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading data from a Mysql database like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo $row['field1'] . " " . $row['field2'];

  }
```

Instead of outputting the records like this:

```
 echo $row['field1'] . " " . $row['field2'];
```

I need to get them into the format below:

```
$list = array(

        array('field1'=>'something here', 'field2'=>'something else')

  );
```

How do I do this?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php, there's an example of how to do exactly what you want, in the documentation for what you're using.

Comment: Don't even know what to say. What's wrong with `$result[] = array('field1'=>$row['field1'], 'field2'=>$row['field2'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $list[] = $row;

}
```